# Utilization of data from satellites mantained by India

Tags: isro, mars-orbiter-mission, raw-data

What are the prerequisites to utilize the data from 'astrosat' or 'mangalyaan'. My aim is to check how useful the data generated by an Indian scopes are? I could not make any sense in the catalogs.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, the data from ASTROSAT is not available as the [instruments are still being checked](http://astron-soc.in/outreach/2015/09/astrosat-faq/). According to Astronomical Society of India,

> ASTROSAT is a public observatory and is therefore available for any potential researcher in India and abroad. The first 6 months after launch will be devoted to extensive tests of all the systems. The next 6 months will be for observations of the sky by the teams that built the instruments. However, a year after the launch, a certain fraction of ASTROSAT time will be available for any scientist in India who proposes an observation that passes review. Two years after the launch, international scientists can apply as well. In addition, once an observation is done by ASTROSAT and some time has passed, the entire data will be made public to anyone who is interested !

For using data from Mangalyaan, [a proposal has to be submitted to ISRO](http://www.isro.gov.in/pslv-c25-mars-orbiter-mission/announcement-of-opportunity-utilising-mars-orbiter-mission-data-mcc):

> Proposals could be submitted by individuals or a group of scientists, academicians belonging to recognized institutions, universities and government organizations of India.

The present deadline for submission of proposals has already passed (Oct 10). I think the rules for using data from Mars Orbiter Mission (MOM) is similar to ASTROSAT. First, the data will be available to Indian and partner institutions and then for others. In general, the data will be made available to the public after some time, usually after the results have been published.